# how can I iterate through a json with a list of objects inside?

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

I have a json object which I receive in my jenkins pipeline through a url and I parse it like this:

```
def url = 'http://localhost:8080/job/find_issues/22/cppcheck/all/api/json'
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText( new URL(url).text )
```

Which has this format

```
{
"_class": "io.jenkins.plugins.analysis.core.restapi.ReportApi",
"issues": [],
"size": 100,
"toString": "- (-): 100 issues (0 duplicates)"
}
```

which can have a different number of issues inside the `issues` list, each of them having this structure:

```
{
"addedAt": 0,
"authorEmail": "-",
"authorName": "-",
"baseName": "stat_obj.cpp",
"category": "",
"columnEnd": 0,
"columnStart": 0,
"commit": "-",
"description": "",
"fileName": "D:/Source/Game/objects/stat_obj.cpp",
"fingerprint": "D2CD3A23FB45D3A1F1C3CB8BE5241602",
"lineEnd": 5592,
"lineStart": 5592,
"message": "Unmatched '('. Configuration: 'DEBUGMAPEXPLORATION'.",
"moduleName": "",
"origin": "cppcheck",
"originName": "CPPCheck",
"packageName": "-",
"reference": "19",
"severity": "HIGH",
"toString": "D:/Source/Game/objects/stat_obj.cpp(5592,0): syntaxError: : Unmatched '('. Configuration: 'DEBUGMAPEXPLORATION'.",
"type": "syntaxError"
}
```

How can I access the Issues list and the iterate through each one of the issues and them through each of the issue keys?
I have tried different ways, lastly I have this:

```
for (entry in json) {
    if(entry.key == "issues")
    {
        for (issue in entry.value) {
            entry.value.each{ key, value ->
                if (key == "fileName"){
                    errorsList.add(value)
                }
                if (key == "lineStart"){
                    errorsList.add(value)
                }
                if (key == "message"){
                    errorsList.add(value)
                }
                if (key == "severity"){
                    errorsList.add(value)
                }
                if (key == "type"){
                    errorsList.add(value)
                }
                def msg = "New ERROR found in static analysis, TYPE OF ERROR ${errorsList[4]}, SEVERITY: ${errorsList[3]}, ERROR MESSAGE: ${errorsList[2]}, FILE ${errorsList[0]} AT LINE: ${errorsList[1]}"
                println msg
                errorsList.clear()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I call print `msg` I have something like this:

```
17:13:09  New ERROR found in static analysis, TYPE OF ERROR null, SEVERITY: null, ERROR MESSAGE: null, FILE null AT LINE: null
```

It seems like I am over iterating but I do not get to see where is the mistake...

Comment: Side note: you don't have to iterate a map and look for keys. You can access the value directly via the key.  E.g. `json.issues.each{ ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
json.issues.each{issue->
    def msg = "New ERROR found in static analysis, TYPE OF ERROR ${issue.type}"+
              ", SEVERITY: ${issue.severity}, ERROR MESSAGE: ${issue.message}"+
              ", FILE ${issue.fileName} AT LINE: ${issue.lineStart}"
    println msg
}
```

Comment: I was complicating it much more of what it actually was, junior mistakes I guess... Thanks a lot!